# "How to add or remove login credentials" pop-up on the Contact page has incorrect instructions

Tags: bug, status-review, popups, contact, my-logins

On the [Contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page, after selecting "I need to add or remove login credentials", the following pop-up is shown:

> #### How to add or remove login credentials
>
> Open up your [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) and click “my logins” in the top right.
>
> This should bring up a pop-up that lists your logins. Click “remove” next to each login to remove it.
>
> To add a login, click “add more logins…” at the bottom of the box. Choose your new login method and follow the steps to confirm.

The problematic statements are as follows:

1. > Open up your [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) and click “my logins” in the top right.

   There is no option called "my logins" in the *top right* on any page in a user's profile. This option is only available in the Settings tab, under the "Access" heading. This is not mentioned in the above instruction, so the user has to figure out where to go next from the Activity page. Here, the instructions could be made clearer, or add a link leading directly to the [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) page.
2. > This should bring up a pop-up that lists your logins. Click “remove” next to each login to remove it.

   There is no *pop-up* involved here. "My Logins" has its own *page*.

Can these instructions please be updated?

Here are two variations that could be used:

1. > #### How to add or remove login credentials
   >
   > Open up the Settings tab in your [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) and click “Your logins” under the "Access" heading in the left column.
   >
   > This should bring up a *page* that lists your logins. Click “Remove” next to each login to remove it.
   >
   > To add a login, click “Add more logins…” at the bottom of the *page*. Choose your new login method and follow the steps to confirm.
2. > #### How to add or remove login credentials
   >
   > Open up the [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) page from the Settings tab in your user profile page.
   >
   > This should bring up a *page* that lists your logins. Click “Remove” next to each login to remove it.
   >
   > To add a login, click “Add more logins…” at the bottom of the *page*. Choose your new login method and follow the steps to confirm.