# Why was the contact page interface changed suddenly?

Tags: support, design, contact

This is how the contact page roughly used to look like (Source: Internet Archive):

[image]

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

When was the page modified and if you don't mind, what was the reason for modifying the page?

Comment: More clicks = less requests. (aka don't make it easy to submit contact request to reduce the flood.)

Comment: It was changed [less than half a month ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20230114231818/https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: It was changed this morning. :) Mostly, we added a new option for mods and the drop-down was getting really long... but we can give a fuller explanation. Just need some time.

Comment: I actually think this is more usable than a giant drop down, and probably lends itself better to accessibility options.

Comment: @ColleenV it's making the action of submitting a form more complicated by adding "steps", which are totally not needed. It used to be simple, now it's not.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars It used to be simple for you... having a screen reader list all of the things in the drop down and trying to keep them all in your head so you can pick the best one instead of just picking a category and drilling down is better for some people. More clicks != worse usability. A giant uncategorized list is only simple for people familiar with its contents. I can think of a number of ways sorting requests into categories makes the code more maintainable too, but I don't know if that's *why* they did it  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to expand on Kristina's initial answer, which was much appreciated while we drafted and reviewed this longer one -

The main reason for this change is that we we wanted to make a new option on the /contact page for moderators, so they could have an easy and clear way to let us know if they wanted to step down. We strongly feel that it's important for mods to know that we support them both as moderators and when they feel it's time to end their tenure, so having this option gives them a clear way to reach out to us about it.

[image: The contact page showing the options for the Account issue section with "I want to step down as site moderator" selected. It has prefilled boxes for email address and a space to put in an explanation for the request.]

As we're making changes like this, we're asking our design team to think about the pages we'll be touching a bit more broadly and ask if there are simple changes that can be made at the same time to improve usability. In this case, they mentioned a few things:

1. The list was getting really long and there was concern from an accessibility aspect that it might be complicated for people to find the correct option.

   - We worked on coming up with reasonable categories that would help users find the option they needed without having to wait for screen readers to scan through all of the options.
   - We also want to make sure that people got to the right team to help them more quickly, but also to assure sane workflows for people on those teams.
2. The two-column format was more complicated than it needed to be and meant that, on mobile devices, the Help Center search was *below* the contact form. This means that many users likely weren't searching the Help Center at all.

   - Our Support team often replies to contacts with links to exactly these pages, so we want to increase the likelihood of people finding them on their own, thereby reducing the workload on our Support team.
   - We reworked the page so that the Help Center search was the first box users would encounter. Adding some keywords here will show a handful of results and point to a full list if there are more than fit in the page.
     [image: Help Center search field filled in with "closed" and showing some common help results about closed questions]

We'll be communicating with our Support team and checking in to see if this is increasing or decreasing the number of contacts they get and whether it's impacting how likely people are to use the correct contact reason when they do write in. If we need to make further improvements to this page, we'll look into that after we get some data to base our next steps on.

Comment: Was this new workflow tested to see if it'd work with keyboard-only users?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Catija!

Answer (score 15):

As [Catija said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1287792), we wanted to add another option into the contact menu, and decided to take that opportunity to improve it a bit as well - sorting the contact options into topics and generally improving the UX for folks using the form. I implemented it myself - let us know if you spot any issues!

Comment: Can you talk about the new option for mods?

Comment: BTW, please consider resolving a related issue: ["How to add or remove login credentials" pop-up on the Contact page has incorrect instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381975). Thanks!

Comment: Please add punctuation (question mark) for the titles of dialogue boxes (eg: "How to recover your password", "How to recover your password", etc.) shown when one clicks options under 'Account Issue' option.

Comment: Sorry but I consider it worse user experience. I might be simple, but for me less clicks means it's more simple to do something. Adding steps and categories makes it more complicated for one who just want to submit a form.

Comment: @RandomPerson A question mark would be appropriate if it read “How do I…”, but wouldn’t be appropriate for “How to…”.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Sorry. English isn't my native language. Please share some relevant links regarding this. I'll go through them.

Comment: @RandomPerson No apologies necessary! I vaguely recall seeing some links regarding this in one of [This_is_NOT_a_forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/63550/this-is-not-a-forum)'s edit summaries, but I don't know how to look for them now. For starters, you could take a look at this question on [english.se], and its accepted answer: [Question marks in titles, in particular those beginning 'How to ...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/457180)

Comment: @RandomPerson I'm guessing the new option is  "I want to step down as a site moderator" (at least, I can't remember seeing that one before) which is only shown when opening the contact link from the footer of a site you actually moderate. Which is nice!

Comment: If I change the main category after picking a main category and subcategory, the form with my email, space for my comments and submit button is still displayed. I didn't test whether it would break anything to try to keep going without selecting a subcategory in the new category, but I think there's the possibility of unexpected behavior there...

Comment: Yes, the new option is stepping down as a site moderator. And @ColleenV most categories have the same options so they don't disappear when you change categories unless you pick a category that has different or additional options. Please let me know if you've experienced something different from that.

Comment: @kristinalustig The problem is that I think I can submit a form without selecting a sub category, which is a different code path than if I don't change categories.  This will likely haunt you in the future if you want to expand the capability and allows the "why can't I ask a question" folks to bypass the guidance. I don't know your code base, so I may be out of line, but I've learned the hard way not to ignore stuff like this.

Comment: @kristinalustig The new page looks great! One minor bit of feedback: can it use a different `?` icon when in dark mode on SO? That icon is quite hard to read with dark mode on: https://i.imgur.com/NdjpKmz.png - if it helps, here's the URL of the page that I was viewing with dark mode on https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: This is a screenshot showing the problem with not clearing the form if I change categories: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q302.png I can submit a Trust and Safety support request without filling in the appropriate category or getting the correct form.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for pointing this out, if you haven't already, could you please create a top-level post describing the issue? It helps us a lot with tracking bugs and other issues, since I might not end up being the person to fix it.